# Meditation or practicing technique has benefits of prenatal elaboration?

Tags: meditation-recommendation, meditation-effects, technique

I had heard in the yoga class there's something like prenatal elaboration and it's benefits. Then if a pregnant woman will practice meditation or techniques so baby will born wise, calm, intelligent, kind and curiosity of Dhamma ? Will it born heartily and spiritually Buddhist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one make positive vibration (Kamma) this effect people around you. This is like the hanky effect. Say you wrap a perfumed flower (good person) then the hanky (another person) then the hanky will also smell good. If you warp dried fish (bad person) then the hanky will smell bad. Likewise if the mother is creating good vibrations then the child maybe influenced.

Also if the mother has been good even before conception then this would attract a good child with also more merit.

Answer (score 1):

'Birth', comprises the entire embryonic process beginning with conception and ending with Giving Birth (Childbirth). It is the springing into existence of the groups materiality, feeling, perception, mental constructions, & consciousness. So a calmer and more focused mind in meditation has pass to a child in the womb, as this [study by the Vivekananda Yoga Research Foundation in India](http://eocinstitute.org/meditation/meditation-benefits-for-pregnancy/) shows.